# Flutter: initialize and filter listview by date in flutter dart

Tags: android, flutter, datetime, dart

How to retrieve json data whose date is greater than datetime.now () and display it in a listview in flutter dart?

Answer (score 1):

You can use both [isBefore](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/DateTime/isBefore.html) and [isAfter](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.9.3/dart-core/DateTime/isAfter.html) from [DateTime](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.9.3/dart-core/DateTime-class.html) class and based on the result filter your data, refer the [doc](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.9.3/dart-core/DateTime-class.html) for the detailed implementation.

Comment: here is my code in the insialization of listeview:
     for(int i=0;i<vente.length;i++){

        listevente=vente.where ((x) =>
          DateTime.parse(DateTime.now().toIso8601String().substring(0,10)).isAfter( DateTime.parse(x.date[i].toString().substring(7,17)))
        ,
      ).
      toList();}

Answer (score 0):

To be able to order a list of DateTime data :

```
int millisecondsSinceEpoch = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch;
  List<DateTime> list = [
    DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(millisecondsSinceEpoch - 2000),
    DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(millisecondsSinceEpoch - 5000),
    DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(millisecondsSinceEpoch - 10000),
    DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(millisecondsSinceEpoch - 400),
  ];
  
  list.sort((DateTime a, DateTime b) {return a.compareTo(b);});
  
  for (var x in list) {
    print(x.toIso8601String());
  }
```

Result of this :

> 2020-09-10T13:08:05.706
> 2020-09-10T13:08:10.706
> 2020-09-10T13:08:13.706
> 2020-09-10T13:08:15.306

Then you will be able to render in in a listview with :

```
ListView(children: list.map((DateTime date) => DateDisplayWidget(date)).toList());
```

(with the DateDisplayWidget of your choice)

Comment: I have to retrieve date from json data and compare it with datenow and display listeview